# How do I prevent response to be logged from specific route in Hapi.js using good?

Tags: hapi.js

I'm using good-squeeze the following way

```
// ...
{
  module: 'good-squeeze',
  name: 'Squeeze',
  args: [
    {
      log: '*',
      response: '*',
      request: '*'
    }
  ]
},
// ...
```

When I access `localhost:3000/health` it logs

```
2016-09-28T10:50:26.652, [response] http://0.0.0.0:3000: post /health {} 200 (321ms)
```

How do I prevent response logging from this specific route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible to do it using `good-squeeze` so I've created my own good plugin which will exclude log when it's related to `/health` route.

```
const Stream = require('stream');

class ExcludePath extends Stream.Transform {

  constructor() {
    super({ objectMode: true });
  }

  _transform(data, enc, next) {

    if (data.route === '/health') {
      return next();
    }

    return next(null, data);
  }

}

module.exports = ExcludePath;
```